# Set aspnet textbox height based on text on page load

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I am looking to set the height of an aspnet textbox based on the amount of text so there is no need to scroll on page load when text is loaded from a database field. I need to do this in code behind so the height is stored on the server.

I am able to resize the textbox using javascript as text is entered or removed however I need this to also be done on page load and again that height be stored server side.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try using http://www.impressivewebs.com/textarea-auto-resize/ - In short, it's a jquery function that allows you to invoke a resize.  Once referenced, use $('#myTextarea').autoResize(); on keyup, blur, whenever.. to invoke the resize function.

Credit: https://css-tricks.com/textarea-tricks/